# StackOverflow error al iniciar Hilo

Tags: java

En esta clase estoy intentando poner 4 hilos los los cuales van a hacer que se cambie la imagen en algunos labels que tengo en mi JFrame pero al momento de tratar de iniciar el Hilo me parace el **Error de StackOverflow** tengo un contador el cual inicia en 0 y el cual con ayuda del Switch me va a ir cambiando la imagen y aumentando el contador para seguir con la siguente

```
`public class Hilo extends Thread {
Principal p = new Principal();              
int cont = 0;
Icon icono;
public Hilo() {    
}
public void Run() {
    Icon icono;
    switch (cont) {
        case 0:
            cont = 1;
            this.icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blink/1.png"));
            p.Label1.setIcon(this.icono);
        break;
        case 1:
            cont = 2;
            this.icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blink/2.png"));
            p.Label1.setIcon(this.icono);
        break;
        case 2:
            cont = 2;
            this.icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blink/3.png"));
            p.Label1.setIcon(this.icono);
        break;
        case 3:
            cont = 0;
            icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/blink/4.png"));
            p.Label1.setIcon(icono);
        break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ex);
    }        
}}
```

*JFrame donde trato de iniciar el Hilo por medio de un botón el cual es el boton1 y el boton2 para detenerlo*

```
package Clases;

public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Hilo h = new Hilo(); 
public Principal() {
    initComponents();             
}
private void Boton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
     h.start();
}                                      
private void Boton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    h.stop();
}                                      
public static void main(String args[]) {     
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Principal().setVisible(true);               
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que en Hilo creas en tiempo de construcción un objeto Principal y en Principal creas en tiempo de construcción un objeto Hilo, que a su vez crea otro Principal y a su vez otro Hilo, y así sucesivamente hasta que se produce el desbordamiento de pila (stack overflow) tras crear millones de objetos principal e hilo.

Creo que se te ha colado el `Principal p = new Principal();` en la clase Hilo. Elimina esa línea. Si necesitas una referencia del principal, pásasela por constructor.

### Te lo detallo

Como he dicho estás creando en Hilo otro principal. Si cada principal tiene su propio Hilo, lo que podrías hacer es pasarle la referencia de dicho Principal al Hilo, por constructor.

```java
class Hilo extends Thread {
    // ...
    Principal p;
    public Hilo(Principal p) {   
        this.p = p;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Y en Principal

```java
public class Principal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Hilo h;

    public Principal {
        initComponentes();
        h = new Hilo(this);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Si la ocupo ya que con esa mando a llamar al label para ponerle la imagen

Comment: @SEBASTIANJIMENEZGALLARDO Ciertamente. He actualizado mi respuesta. Verás que te sugiero que en lugar de crear un nuevo Principal en Hilo, le pases la referencia del principal ya creado al propio hilo.

Comment: Me sirvió, muchas gracias :D